# Possible reason for listview not displaying on Android 4.0.3 (API 15) but works fine on 4.1.2 (API 16)?

Tags: android

I am tasked with determining why a 5 year old app (worked on by a few teams) that supports API 8 through API 19 only has this particular issue with API 15.

The issue is the app is not displaying any data in it's 2 ListViews.

A few details:

1. There are no errors reported in logcat.  I run the app on both API 15 and API 16 emulators and their logcats look almost identical.
2. Calling listview.getAdapter().getCount() does return an expected value greater than 0.

(UPDATE)
3. listview.getItem() and listview.getView() are NOT being called.

4. listview.getVisibility() does return View.VISIBLE
5. Oddly, backing out of the app and restarting it, allows the data to display(!)

I have searched for several days now on what could be the cause of this working fine on API 16, as in "what was fixed" between 15 and 16, but nothing that makes sense showed up. I have been shy to ask here due to this making me sound crazy :-)
I'm hoping someone has encountered this with 4.0.3 and can give me my next path to solve this.  Posting code will be very difficult, but any reasonable requests will be happily complied with. Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some codes that will help in finding the error.

Comment: Thanks, and I would agree, but I wouldn't know where to begin to post something useful, it is a very full-featured social media app and the code to populate the listview from a server is across numerous classes.  It's hard to imagine there being something wrong with the listview code when it (very consistently) works fine on all the APIs except 15 (where it consistently fails).  Setting up a listview is fairly trivial stuff that I've done many times before, and I don't see anything special about this one... I'm looking for something weird about 4.0.3 that someone may have encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one is going to believe me ;-), but the fix was to remove:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

...from a LinearLayout in the app's main layout file (which contains a support ViewPager and whose root was a TabHost, not that those necessarily matter).

I couldn't believe this myself, so I replaced and removed it a couple of times and it would alternate between "breaking" and "working".

I have no idea why this worked, but I've listed the .xml file here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/aim_light_grey" >

    <!-- android:animateLayoutChanges below was the problem!!! -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"   
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/no_network_indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/warn_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_not_connected"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@color/light_grey"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/not_connected"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="44dip"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image_logo_accessibility_description"
                android:src="@drawable/action_1" />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: I believe you! This fixed the same issue for me, also only on 4.0.3.